# I have used a glyphicon as a dropdown menu, yet after having applied numerous suggestions it still wont work?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, glyphicons

I am completely new at this so I apologize if this question has been repeated way too many times. Yet I have tried countless amounts of suggestions and it still won't work.

I used the bootstrap suggestion for the dropdown glyphicon menu.

So I am starting to think that its got something to do with my background (which is a jpg image)?

```
  <!-- Single button --> 
 <div class="btn-group"> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> 
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> 
  </button> 
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
<li class="divider"></li> 
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li> 
</ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show some example html/css please?

Comment: <!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

Comment: It won't let me post in the actual question...but this is my html for it. It didn't say anything about css?